# Apex : copying application breaks all workspace applications

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex Oracle application A. The application works fine. It has some public pages without authentication.

When I copy this application, all the other applications of the workspace break and whenever I try to launch one, I'm getting the login page (eventhough I'm browsing public pages)

I just delete the copy I created, everything starts working again.

I tried with the option "**Copy Supporting Object Definitions**" enabled and disabled and I'm getting the same problem.

Has anyone experienced such a problem please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Can you break down into "export project" and check which importe part or the export breaks the application?

Comment: How do you do that please ?

Comment: When you edit your application there is button Export/Import .. when you export the application a sql-File is created. It's possible to change that file and remove some parts. And afterward import it in the other instance

Comment: Well here I'm using directly the copy feature. I don't not generate the sql file and import again. In case it's needed, which sql file part should I check ? Thanks

Comment: Sure you described the copy feature .. but probable if you import the exported code it's easier to find the issue. Only an idea how to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when I copy the application to a previously used application identifier.

I had an application with id 150 and had some trouble with it. I deleted it, and when copying the application to id 150 again, it breaks all the rest.

I can't explain it but when I copy the application with a fresh identifier it works.